# Blender won't respect video alpha

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

I've exported a video in Davinci Resolve (Container: Quicktime, Codec:DNxHR) which is a codec that is alpha approved. But when i import the alpha video into blender, blender for some reason doesn't show the alpha channel.
Then I exported another video (Container: Quicktime, Codec: Grass Valley)
And when I import the alpha video into blender, it has strange green clipping (see photo). **Why is this happening?**[image]

Comment: If the documentation is correct Blender doesn't support alpha for DNxHR. (See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/video_formats.html#ffmpeg-video-codecs)

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way. Thanks, Do you know what the deal is with the green clipping?

Comment: No sorry, I don't know.